# Dynamically add images in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Assume you are working in a notebook. Is there a fancy way to generate markdown cells to display images (in the same notebook) by giving a list of filenames and captions?

In other words, given a string template (with a number of placeholders) of what should go in a markdown cell, is there a way to loop on the list of the placeholder-values to generate all the cells needed?

Right now my lazy way is the following (not so lazy as it involves a copy/paste of the md code in cells).

```
from string import Template

img_list = !ls figs/start_*.png

fig_template = Template('''<figure>
    <img src="$fn" alt='$capt'>
    <figcaption> Figure $fig_idx. $capt</figcaption>
</figure>'''
)

for idx, img in enumerate(img_list, 1):
    print fig_template.substitute(fn=img, capt=img, fig_idx=idx)
```

Comment: Not really relevant, but do you know that `enumerate` has a keyword only parameter called `start`? Instead of doing `fig_idx=idx+1` you can just use `enumerate(img_list, start=1)` and use `fig_idx=idx`.

Comment: that is actually very nice to know! I edited the question following your comment, thx @Bakuriu